Cross-compilation of a C++ program for Windows on Debian with Clang & Mingw-w64
I am trying to compile a c++ program on debian 12.05.00 with clang for windows. When I run the following command:
clang++ --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.cpp
I get the following output:
main.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include<iostream>
        ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

I would be grateful for any assistance in solving the problem.
What I have tried so far:

Installing gcc, mingw-w64 & clang
Compiling the program with clang: clang++ -o main main.cpp -> works just fine
Compiling the program with mingw-w64: x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -> works also fine
Compiling with clang and target: clang++ --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -> shows the above error

What I also know is that clang has to find the headers/lib files. So in short I tried to find the libs this with this command:
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.cpp --verbose
I get the following output:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --libexecdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --with-headers --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --enable-lto --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --enable-libatomic --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-dependency-tracking SED=/bin/sed
Thread model: win32
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 12-win32 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main.exe' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/cc1plus -quiet -v -U_REENTRANT main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -o /tmp/cc24ZVrH.s
GNU C++17 (GCC) version 12-win32 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.1-p1, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP

warning: MPFR header version 4.1.1-p1 differs from library version 4.2.0.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/include/c++
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/include/c++/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/include-fixed
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++17 (GCC) version 12-win32 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.1-p1, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP

warning: MPFR header version 4.1.1-p1 differs from library version 4.2.0.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 388fe3850a437d75cb1b8b3548fb400f
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main.exe' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as -v -o /tmp/ccxoZGfx.o /tmp/cc24ZVrH.s
GNU assembler version 2.40 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.40
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main.exe' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'main.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccJna9iv.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o main.exe /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib /tmp/ccxoZGfx.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/crtend.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main.exe' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'main.'


So from what I can see is that the libs are located under:
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-win32/
Running:
clang++ --target=x86_64-pc-win64-mingw32 --sysroot=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix -o main.exe main.cpp --verbose
Yields:
Debian clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
 "/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -mms-bitfields -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/lukas/Downloads -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.6 -isysroot /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++//x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++//backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++/ -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++//x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++//backward -internal-isystem include/c++ -internal-isystem include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -internal-isystem include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.6/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/lukas/Downloads -ferror-limit 19 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -exception-model=seh -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/main-e19f09.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.6 based upon LLVM 14.0.6 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++//x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++//backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++//x86_64-w64-mingw32
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++//backward
 /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.6/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include
End of search list.
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++/ios:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++/iosfwd:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12-posix/include/c++/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found

I would need help at this point to understand what I am doing wrong. Whether I have installed the wrong versions or what else I need to do to find the libs. I'm not necessarily looking for a finished tool, but to understand what I need to do.
